# New Dell & old Compaq laptop DOS PXE boot with wireless router

Tags: boot, pxe

I have a Netgear wireless router connected to the internet, and a new Dell laptop.

How can I PXE boot my old Compaq laptop, which is connected to the router with an ethernet LAN cable?

Even a simple boot to DOS would be enough, or booting from an USB or a CD device. The main problem is, that the HDD drive doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Must such old computers, especially old laptops, can't boot from the network. If they could boot, you had a lot of trouble with their network-running OS.

In your place I used a live cd, for example from ubuntu, with a permanent data area, and used this machine - or at least for a simple vnc/rdesktop session to control your another laptop.

Comment: Problem is live CD is not working, i have to remove the CD drive to boot the system through HDD, but HDD is already corrupt

Comment: @shunmu What about the hdd trouble? Maybe you need only a badblock scan?